# Show PHP header in FireBug

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, wamp

I have index.php running on WAMP and all I want to do is return 200 Ok header. I have:

```
echo "Index3<br />";
//All I need to do is execute a method.
$request_method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
echo "Serving " .$request_method;
//And send back a response header.
header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n<br />";
}
```

I see nothing in Firebug(in both the Console and Net tab). In the foreach I see all headers about Accept, Connect, Cache etc. but no 200? I only get something in the Console when I change to a 400 response in the code above, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers must be the first thing sent to the browser. You have `echo` statements before your `header`. You cannot do this.

Also, the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` is not considered a "header" like `Accept`, `Cache` are. It will generally be available under some `statusCode` property. Firebug should show it in the "Network" tab. It will be listed next to each request.

Comment: Ok, I move this line to the top:
header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');
but still nothing?

The Net tab just shows nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `header()` needs to come before any `echo` statements.  Once you start echoing content, it's too late to modify the HTTP headers.

This is because the headers precede the HTTP body.  If you can't control the use of `echo` before header calls, you can use output buffers---[ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_end_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php)---to prevent them from interfering with the headers.